# Which subcategory of the derived category of an algebra has a Serre functor?

Tags: representation-theory, homological-algebra

My question concerns which subcategory of the derived category has a Serre functor.

In
[Calabi-Yau algebras, Section 7.2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612139.pdf)
V. Ginzburg defines the category $D^{fproj}(A)$ of a left and right Noetherian algebra $A$ as the 
*derived category of bounded complexes of projective finitely generated $A$-modules*.
By Lemma 7.2.8 the category $D^{fproj}(A)$ admits a Serre duality formula except that the Serre functor $\mathbb{S}$ does not preserve the category $D^{fproj}(A)$.

If the Noetherian algebra $A$ is well-behaved like a symmetric $R$-order over some central subring $R$ of Krull dimension $d$, then Theorem 7.2.14 of Ginzburg's paper implies that
the category $D^{fproj}(A)$ is *$d$-Calabi-Yau*, that is, preserved by the Serre functor $\mathbb{S}$ which becomes isomorphic to the shift functor $[d]$.

My question boils down to the following:

**Why is $D^{fproj}(A)$ not the same as the perfect derived category $\mathrm{perf} A$?**

By $\mathrm{perf} A$ I mean the full subcategory of the big derived category $D(Mod A)$ whose objects are given by complexes which are quasi-isomorphic to bounded complexes of projective finitely generated $A$-modules.

The question becomes only interesting if $A$ is not a finite-dimensional $k$-algebra but an algebra with non-Artinian center like $A = k[x,y]/(xy)$.

Here are two additional notes:

1. Assume as above, that $A$ is a symmetric order with center of Krull dimension $d> 0$.
   If there was equality $D^{fproj}(A) = \mathrm{perf} A$ then any tilting complex of $A$ would be just some shift of $A$ by Serre duality. However, this cannot be true since preprojective algebras of affine type are symmetric orders which have non-trivial tilting complexes.
2. Results by Iyama and Reiten 
   ([Fomin-Zelevinsky mutation and tilting modules over Calabi-Yau algebras, Theorem 3.7](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605136.pdf))
   on the Serre functor suggest that $D^{fproj}(A)$ should mean the category $\mathrm{perf}_{{fl}} A$ of perfect complexes $P$ such that the cohomology $H^i(P)$ at each degree $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ has finite length. However, I cannot see that from Ginzburg's definition.

Comment: For what value of $Z$ does your example $A=k[x,y]/(xy)$ satisfy the conditions 7.2(i) and (ii) of the paper?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. In that case $Z$ can be the central subring $k[x+y]$. Then $Z$ is a regular ring, so Cohen-Macaulay without zero-divisiors, and $A$ is a free $Z$-module of rank 2. To make it fit the assumptions we should also assume that $k = \mathbb{C}$.